# Display webform results data in a Google Chart

Tags: theming, 6, webforms, charts

I'm trying to display webform results as [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/). I'm doing this on the theme layer by overriding theme_webform_results_analysis() on my theme's template.php file and using the [Chart module](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart). Drupal 6.22, [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) 6.x-3.11.

The webform analysis page normally shows the data in a table, so I'm trying to hack apart the arrays for that table to pass stuff into the [Chart API](https://www.drupal.org/node/2422733).

**EDIT**: I figured out how to use var_dump and found that the better approach might be to get up in the $row_data and $questions arrays separately (instead of using the $rows array that I had in the first version of this question, which was a mashup of both arrays).

**EDIT #2**: I think I've discovered how to grab each piece of the original $questions and $row_data arrays (see below - the foreach in the other foreach). So now I need to get those pieces into proper arrays (1 per question) and find a way to iterate through all of those.

Here's what I've got in template.php:

```
/**
 * Output the content of the Analysis page.
 * @see webform_results_analysis()
 */
function mytheme_webform_results_analysis($node, $data, $sids = array(), $analysis_component = NULL) {

  foreach ($data as $cid => $row_data) {

    if (is_array($row_data)) {

      // get the questions, put them in an array
      $questions = array();
      $questions[] = array('data' => check_plain($node->webform['components'][$cid]['name']));

      // this will print everything out in the right order - it really needs to
      // make an array for each question that looks like $test_chart below
      foreach ($questions as $question) {
        print $question['data'] . '<br />'; // questions 
        foreach ($row_data as $key => $value) {
          print $value[0] . '<br />'; // labels
          print $value[1] . '<br />'; // results 
        }
      }

      // Set up the chart
      $chart = array(
        '#chart_id' => 'webform_analysis',
        '#type' => CHART_TYPE_PIE_3D,
        '#size' => chart_size(658, 250)
      );

      // not real data here, this just shows the format I'm shooting for
      $test_chart = array(
        'option 1' => '12',
        'option 2' => '45',
        'option 3' => '122'
      ); 

      // separate the above array into labels and values, add a percentage to the label
      foreach ($test_chart as $key => $value) {
        $chart['#data'][] = $test_chart[$key];
        $chart['#labels'][] = strip_tags($key) . ' (' . round($test_chart[$key], 2) .  '%)';
      }
      // pick some colors
      $chart['#data_colors'][] = 'b0c73d';
      $chart['#data_colors'][] = '667323';
      $chart['#data_colors'][] = '221f1f';

      $output = chart_render($chart);    
    }
  }

  if (count($row_data) == 0) {
    $output = t('There are no submissions for this form.');
  }

  // return the data that goes into chart function, just for testing
  // return $chart_data; 

  // someday, this might return a set of webform charts. right now it returns the fake test chart
  // return $output;
}
```

Comment: did you solve your own question.  If so post your own answer

Comment: Nope, I haven't figured this out yet. It's on hold for now until I finish reading "Beginning PHP and MySQL5: from novice to professional" ([link](http://books.google.com/books/about/Beginning_PHP_and_MySQL_5.html?id=B_OCVIL_W80C)), and then I'm going to give it another shot. I struck out at getting help online, so I figured I just need to get a better handle on fundamentals before attempting something this tricky.

Answer (score 2):

There is another Drupal charts module that provides support for webforms: http://drupal.org/project/fusioncharts

Fusionchart has a little sub-module called fusioncharts_webform

Comment: Thanks for your response! I looked at FusionCharts, but it's not a good fit for my project since it uses Flash and we'd need the paid version - we try to stick to open-source solutions. But it looks nice, I bet that solves this problem for lots of people.

Answer (score 1):

More then 3 years later now, I know, but things have evolved a bit since then ...

By only considering the title of this question, one might want to address this via the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module these days (though the original question started from [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart), which is another module). And this in combination with either [Webform Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_chart) or [Webform Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_charts).

Depending on what your actual needs are today, it appears that with these 2 Webform related modules, quite a lot can be achieved by site building activities (probably no more need for Drupal developers skills).  Refer to bullet 5 in [Modules facilitating charting via the Charts module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2389465#facilitatingmodules) for some more details about these Webform Chart(s) modules (and link to an interesting discussion).

Use the [Comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) for potential other alternatives these days (and be ready to really get confused about the dozens of charting modules available ...).

Be aware: I'm a new (co-) maintainer of [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) and [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), and the author of the [Comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985). I'm trying to continue Quicksketch's (amazing) contributions to Charts, who is also the maintainer of Webform, and Webform ChartS (with an 's').

PS: Sorry for all those confusing *chart(s) namespaces, I did not invent them ...

Answer (score 1):

[Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) now integrates with [webform views](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views) ([views cumulative field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_cumulative_field) is also quite usable too).

See also [charts ecosystem](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts/ecosystem) for even more possibilites.